# Creating new column in python pandas df as countif in excel

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have data like this

[image]

and I want to add a new column like below

[image]

Then final data will be like below

[image]

How I can do it in python pandas? Seeking your support

Comment: Take the time to provide the actual data in text format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a minimal example (I do not have data, so I created a dataframe)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

size = 10
df = pd.DataFrame({"2020-01-{:02d}".format(k): np.random.randn(size) for k in range(1, 4)})
```

The dataframe looks like

```
   2020-01-01  2020-01-02  2020-01-03
0   -0.100633   -0.955389   -1.249950
1    0.178421   -0.175384    0.935416
2    0.600968   -0.773636   -1.186054
3   -0.147984   -0.505044   -0.615161
4   -0.627641   -0.409140    1.607050
5    0.855091    0.048863    1.214041
6   -0.108215    0.112185   -1.128229
7   -0.194756    0.486348    2.650181
8    1.464501   -0.530590    1.528327
9    0.248294    0.991100    0.416958
```

To count values you can use a mask as

```
df.loc[:, "counts"] = df[df > 0.08].count(axis=1)
```

Then you get

```
   2020-01-01  2020-01-02  2020-01-03  counts
0   -0.100633   -0.955389   -1.249950       0
1    0.178421   -0.175384    0.935416       2
2    0.600968   -0.773636   -1.186054       1
3   -0.147984   -0.505044   -0.615161       0
4   -0.627641   -0.409140    1.607050       1
5    0.855091    0.048863    1.214041       2
6   -0.108215    0.112185   -1.128229       1
7   -0.194756    0.486348    2.650181       2
8    1.464501   -0.530590    1.528327       2
9    0.248294    0.991100    0.416958       3
```